# Bayesian decision theory - loss function

Tags: probability, self-study, conditional-probability

i am trying to learn  bayesian decision theory. the book that i am using (Kevin Murphy: Machine Learning: A Probabilistic Perspective) - has the following introduction on the action a:

[image]

however - further in the text it refers to P(a|x)

[image]

i am finding it hard to fully understand what P(a|x) means. i read it as hte probability of a certain action a conditional on the covariates x, but i am not sure that this is correct, or how the probability of this action is linked to the loss function. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: It is an expected value. As you can see in the first equality in the second line, $\rho(a \mid x) = \mathbb{E}\left[(y-a)^2 \mid x\right]$.

Comment: I think what's causing the confusion is the author is using the symbol $\rho$ and not $p$.  It's just the symbol he's using for the Bayes risk with respect to that loss function, and doesn't mean to imply that what's on the RHS is a probability.

Comment: This usage is common. Ironically, probably to distinguish it from p.